# How to make embedded videos work in PDFs created by LaTeX?

Tags: video, pdf, adobe, latex

I am on Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit and using Adobe Reader 9.

I am using LaTeX Beamer to create my slideshow. In Windows and MacOS I can open and play the embedded video in Adobe Reader. But I simply can't get it to work in Ubuntu. So right now I do all my stuff including make the presentations in Ubuntu, but then I have to boot to Windows to show it.

[Here is a sample presentation.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3457344/Film_Input.zip) And a [sample .MOV movie](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3457344/dancing_bartenders.mov)

> Try installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras?`

Comment: Are you using Adobe Reader in Ubuntu too?

Comment: Yes. I am using Adobe Reader in Ubuntu for slides. Because I can set Adobe Reader to show it external when clicked on in the slideshow  through LaTeX Beamer. If there is no video I often use normal Document Viewer.

Comment: Please edit your answer with more details on how you create/encode the videos, etc. It may just be a codec issue.

Comment: I use LaTeX Beamer class' \includemovie{film.mov} to include the .mov or .avi file in the document.

Comment: Screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3457344/Screenshot.png

Comment: Please see [Embedding videos and animations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1574/201) at tex.SE. Does this help for you?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)